# Ubuntu 22.04: Dolphin always starts with two tabs open

Tags: 22.04, bug-reporting, dolphin, tabs

when I start Dolphin it always starts with two tabs open. I once had Dolphin open in one window with these two tabs but I don't know why it would put these into its "lexical scope" and from now "till death do us apart" will open with these two tabs open instead of one tab which ought to be home folder?

Do you maybe have a clue as to why or how I can "reset" this behaviour?

Maybe it is part of session restoring. Can I unset/reset the session for certain programs from session-restoring? Would be worth a try maybe.

Comment: **Welcome to the Ask Ubuntu community.** Are you running Kubuntu or Ubuntu? Your question title indicates Ubuntu, but Dolphin is a KDE file manager. Or did you install Dolphin separately? Thanks for providing this additional context so we can better troubleshoot your issue.